# MATLAB: fast and memory efficient solution of a particular linear program

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I have a little programming experience, so I'm pretty sure I didn't code the problem in the optimal way, so I would be happy to hear any hints.

I have two parameters: the dimension of the problem `n` and an `N x N` matrix of constraints `B` where `N = 2n`. In my case `B` is symmetric and has only positive values. I need to solve the following problem

[image: Optimization problem]

That is I need to maximize a certain average of the distances subject to constraints on pairwise distances given by `B(i,j)`.

They way I'm doing it now is an implementation of `linprog(-f,A,b)` where

```
f = ones([1,n])/n;
f = [f -f]
```

and

```
b = reshape(B',numel(B),[])
```

and `A` is defined as follows

```
 A = zeros([N^2,N]);
 for i = 1:N
  for j = 1:N
    if i ~= j
      A((i-1)*N + j,i)   =  1;
      A((i-1)*N + j,j)   = -1;
   end
 end
end
```

However, when `n = 500` even a simple construction of `A` takes quite some time, not to say how long does the solution of the linear program take. Any hints are highly appreciated and please feel free to retag.

Comment: It looks like the dimension of your solution is *2n*.

Comment: @Jacob: you're right, fixed that

Answer (score 2):

First of all, try constructing `A` like so:

```
AI = eye(N);
AV = ones(N, 1);
A = kron(AI, AV) - kron(AV, AI);
```

I think it should run by at least an order of magnitude faster than the way you're creating it.

Comment: Thanks for an advice, but surprisingly it runs slower than the original definition of `A` from my post. For example, when `n = 200` and hence `N = 400` the original code constructs `A` in 0.1 seconds whereas the code you proposed runs in 2 seconds.

Comment: I can provide m-files if you are interested

Answer (score 1):

In addition to creating your problem matrix in a more efficient way, you may want to look into using [glpk](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) with the [glpkmex](http://glpkmex.sourceforge.net/) interface for MATLAB.  I've found that my solution times can decrease substantially.  You may see another order of magnitude decrease depending on the problem size.

If you are an academic you can get either CPLEX or Gurobi licenses for free, which should net you further decreases in solution time without a lot of fiddling around with solver parameters.  This may be necessary with a problem of the size you describe.